# Matlab - multiple if statements active at once

Tags: matlab, oop, object, plot, simulation

Is there a way to get multiple if statements to activate at once. I am working on a simulation, and needmultiple dots to move around a map at once. At the moment i have what is in attached gif (only shows first 3 dots moving). The second dot should start moving around halfway through the first dots journey. Loop is below.

[image]

```
for t = 1:120
    pause(0.1)
    if t == times(1)
        while uav1.position(1) ~= event1(2)
            pause(0.1)
            uav1.position(1) = uav1.position(1) + 5.*(event1(2)./abs(event1(2)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];       
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end
        while uav1.position(2) ~= event1(3)
            pause(0.1)
            uav1.position(2) = uav1.position(2) + 5.*(event1(3)./abs(event1(3)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];       
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end

    elseif t == times(2)
        while uav2.position(1) ~= event2(2)
            pause(0.1)
            uav2.position(1) = uav2.position(1) + 5.*(event2(2)./abs(event2(2)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];      
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end
        while uav2.position(2) ~= event2(3)
            pause(0.1)
            uav2.position(2) = uav2.position(2) + 5.*(event2(3)./abs(event2(3)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];        
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end

    elseif t == times(3)
        while uav3.position(1) ~= event3(2)
            pause(0.1)
            uav3.position(1) = uav3.position(1) + 5.*(event3(2)./abs(event3(2)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];        
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end
        while uav3.position(2) ~= event3(3)
            pause(0.1)
            uav3.position(2) = uav3.position(2) + 5.*(event3(3)./abs(event3(3)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];        
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end

    elseif t == times(4)
        while uav4.position(1) ~= event4(2)
            pause(0.1)
            uav4.position(1) = uav4.position(1) + 5.*(event4(2)./abs(event4(2)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end
        while uav4.position(2) ~= event4(3)
            pause(0.1)
            uav4.position(2) = uav4.position(2) + 5.*(event4(3)./abs(event4(3)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];      
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end

    elseif t == times(5)
        while uav5.position(1) ~= event5(2)
            pause(0.1)
            uav5.position(1) = uav5.position(1) + 5.*(event5(2)./abs(event5(2)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];        
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end
        while uav5.position(2) ~= event5(3)
            pause(0.1)
            uav5.position(2) = uav5.position(2) + 5.*(event5(3)./abs(event5(3)));

            XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
            uav5.position(1),];
            XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
            uav5.position(2),];        
            set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
        end
    end
end

drawnow
```

I have tried using while loops/ more elseif statements etc but no luck.
Thanks

Comment: Your code is not very easy to follow, it needs serious refactoring. Consider this, at each iteration of your main outer loop, everything should get a chance to move just once. So you check all the conditions for each object sequentially and allow them to move just once (maybe by an integer multiple of some distance quantum where the multiplier is proportional to the speed, or maybe you make your time discritization small enough that you can control speed by making objects skip n-1 moves every n iterations). You should also only have one single call to `pause` per iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Restructure your code so it looks like:

```
while cond % only 1 while
   if drawUAV1? 
       % calculate 
   end
   if drawUAV2? 
       % calculate 
   end

   plot(everyhing needed)
   drawnow
   pause(0.01) %only one pause in the code
end
```

separate the drawing from the computing, and dont put pauses everywhere! This way, if 3 UAV need to be updated at the same time, you wont have a problem.